# Libvirt: one NIC, multiple VM, all with Bridged mode

Tags: libvirt

I have a question, is it possible to add one host NIC to multiple Virtual machines in libvirt with both of them using it as bridged mode. I've ran out of NIC-s and I still have 2 VM-s who need bridged connection to the network. That is why I was thinking, if it is possible. I can't really experiment with it in my current environment, but I'm a fast learner. :) Please, make me smarter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with KVM I have several virtual machines all running on the same bridged adapter from a single NIC port. They are just all allocated the same bridge device in their configs.

Comment: Would've been so cool to elaborate. And make this an informative answer :(

Answer (score 1):

Libvirt allow you to create lot of virtual network device such as bridge and virtual NIC.

Here is a docs for helping you to understand the basics of this :

[libvirt network wiki](http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking)

[libvirt virtual network wiki](https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/VirtualNetworking)

Put this in your bookmarks, it's really usefull resources when you begin with libvirt !

Comment: Cheers Mate! I'll start looking it up.